# Windows Error Accessing a Network Share

Tags: windows, network-share, windows-2000

I go to start\run and type in an address for an existing network share for which I have valid permissions (it worked yesterday).

Today, I get the message: "The name limit for the local computer network adapter card was exceeded."

What does this mean?

Comment: http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=The+name+limit+for+the+local+computer+network+adapter+card+was+exceeded&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=a2bb30ecf4f91972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This KB article seems to have quite a bit of info on this issue including ways to pin it down more definitively and resolve:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319504

(and El Otro Dan's google search link is full of links including this KB article)

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an SMB issue, try to restart the "server" service on the fileserver or tweack the smb settings in the server registry. By the way, how is this server used? nb of users, connections?